# okular and external movie player compete for owning the screen?

Tags: okular, presentation

I have been using okular as my primary pdf viewer, and for pdf presentation. Usually my pdf presentations  contains link to external movie files, which, upon clicks, will be opened in an external movie player (I use VLC). I notice that okular in presentation mode seem to compete with VLC for "owing" the screen, and as a result, the screen is flickering back and forth between okular and VLC.  This only happened after some recent updates in Ubuntu 12.04, and only happened when I use the presentation mode.  Is there a solution to avoid this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Which window manager and/or desktop environment are you using? Fullscreen under Linux and X11 is always a bit tricky. Depending on your WM, you may be able to launch VLC and tell your WM automatically to raise the window and/or lower/minify Okular.

Comment: It is actually a unity problem. Try installing ccsm and tweaking there. You should try changing VLC playback mode too, to opengl, for example. I solved this problem and many others by switching to KDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up to call

```
wmctrl -a Okular
```

on globally on pressing some key, say `Win-o` and VLC

```
wmctrl -a VLC
```

on also globally on pressing some other key, say `Win-v`.

Then during presentation You can invoke the window You want manually.

How to call a think in Ubuntu it is a separate question. In Kubuntu there's a `custom shortcut`.